# Logoff remote desktop sessions using access

Tags: vba, ms-access, remote-desktop

I want to log off inactive users form rdp server.

Currently, we do this using the command line

To display information about users logged on to the system.
`C:>quser /server:MyCitrixSVR`

To Log off the terminal session of the remote server 
`LOGOFF [sessionname | sessionid] [/SERVER:servername] [/V]`

How can this be done in Access?

Comment: You want to exec a shell cmd in access?

Comment: Yes, go for it. I am looking for the best possible way but currently, any working solution is okay.

Comment: Easiest way `Shell` command. More Options on `WScipt.Shell`, but I can't believe you don't find that yourself.